# Deserialize nested Json C#

Tags: c#, json, nested

I'm trying to take an XML answer from a rest API and make a JSON string out of it. And from there deserialize it and use it as an strongly typed object in C#. So far I'm only partly successful.

The answer from the API is a list of orders. It looks like this, shortened.

```
<OrderList>
    <Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" href="/__API__/order/1" order_id="1">
        <OrderNo>1</OrderNo>
        <ErpOrderNo xsi:nil="true" />
        <Customer href="/__API__/customer/42">1</Customer>
        <State>DENIED</State>
        <PaymentState>PAID</PaymentState>
        <PaymentIsCaptured>false</PaymentIsCaptured>
        <CaptureTime xsi:nil="true" />
        <PaymentIsCancelled>false</PaymentIsCancelled>
        <CancelTime xsi:nil="true" />
        <CreatedTime>2018-11-06T15:00:00Z</CreatedTime>
        <ChangedTime>2019-05-06T12:45:30Z</ChangedTime>
        <SyncedTime xsi:nil="true" />
    </Order>
    <Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" href="/__API__/order/2" order_id="2">
        <OrderNo>2</OrderNo>
        <ErpOrderNo xsi:nil="true" />
        <Customer href="/__API__/customer/42">1</Customer>
        <State>DENIED</State>
        <PaymentState xsi:nil="true" />
        <PaymentIsCaptured>false</PaymentIsCaptured>
        <CaptureTime xsi:nil="true" />
        <PaymentIsCancelled>false</PaymentIsCancelled>
        <CancelTime xsi:nil="true" />
        <CreatedTime>2018-11-06T15:49:47Z</CreatedTime>
        <ChangedTime>2019-05-06T12:45:30Z</ChangedTime>
        <SyncedTime xsi:nil="true" />
    </Order>
</OrderList>
```

And the JSON looks like this:

```
{
"OrderList": {
    "Order": [{
            "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
            "-href": "/__API__/order/1",
            "-order_id": "1",
            "OrderNo": "1",
            "ErpOrderNo": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            },
            "Customer": {
                "-href": "/__API__/customer/42",
                "#text": "1"
            },
            "State": "DENIED",
            "PaymentState": "PAID",
            "PaymentIsCaptured": "false",
            "CaptureTime": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            },
            "PaymentIsCancelled": "false",
            "CancelTime": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            },
            "CreatedTime": "2018-11-06T15:00:00Z",
            "ChangedTime": "2019-05-06T12:45:30Z",
            "SyncedTime": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
            "-href": "/__API__/order/2",
            "-order_id": "2",
            "OrderNo": "2",
            "ErpOrderNo": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            },
            "Customer": {
                "-href": "/__API__/customer/42",
                "#text": "1"
            },
            "State": "DENIED",
            "PaymentState": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            },
            "PaymentIsCaptured": "false",
            "CaptureTime": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            },
            "PaymentIsCancelled": "false",
            "CancelTime": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            },
            "CreatedTime": "2018-11-06T15:49:47Z",
            "ChangedTime": "2019-05-06T12:45:30Z",
            "SyncedTime": {
                "-xsi:nil": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

The object in C# has been created like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Orderlist OrderList { get; set; }
}

public class Orderlist
{
    public List<Order> Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string xmlnsxsi { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string order_id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    public Erporderno ErpOrderNo { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public object PaymentState { get; set; }
    public string PaymentIsCaptured { get; set; }
    public object CaptureTime { get; set; }
    public string PaymentIsCancelled { get; set; }
    public object CancelTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangedTime { get; set; }
    public Syncedtime SyncedTime { get; set; }
}

public class Erporderno
{
    public string xsinil { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Syncedtime
{
    public string xsinil { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have been trying to deserialize it like this.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlanswer);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
var fromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

The OrderList object gets populated with a list of 300+ orders. But inside the order object it stops working. The Customer object does not get serialized nor does the ErpOrderNr. And I can't figure out why. I have read lots of posts but found no solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are ways to deserialize XML directly into C# objects. No need to convert it to JSON first. I suggest looking into that. But basically, it looks like the customer properties are not deserializing because their property names in the JSON are `-href` and `#text`, not `json` and `text` as you have in your classes. You can use the [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) attribute to indicate the JSON property name to associate with your C# properties.

Comment: @JLRishe - thank you. I have looked into the XML->C# object but the Json is so much cleaner looking. At least from what i have seen. I did what you suggested and it solved the problem for the #Text field. But the -href does not deserialize still :(

Comment: `xsi:nil="true"` means that the value is null. Thus the `SyncedTime` and `CancelTime` properties should be of type `DateTime?`, `ErpOrderNo` should probably be `int?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JsonProperty attribute to help the deserializer, e.g. it doesn't know that "#text" should go to text, so you can add

```
[JsonProperty("#text")
public string Text {get;set;}
```

Comment: It solved the problem for the text field but not for the -href.